# I need javax.microedition.io in android, what can I do?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

Thanks for Ur reply i am writing the program On Android for Connecting SAP soap webservices. for authentication i am using  HttpTransportBasicAuth aht = new  HttpTransportBasicAuth(URL, username , pass); 
 after compilation i got the error in my logcat of eclipse:

```
02-09 11:29:12.062: E/AndroidRuntime(676): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports, add the appropriate library to build path of project- CLDC jar for the javax.microedition.io package.